# Send info to java class from node.js

Tags: java, android, node.js

I am a beginner android developer.

I'm trying to send information from my node.js application to a mobile application I'm developing on android studio.

I could use a server, send a POST request from my node.js app, then simply open the webpage using a WebView element in my mobile app.

But I'm wondering whether it is possible to include the node.js app INSIDE my mobile app, so I could send the data directly to a java activity and then display it to the user as a TextView element.

I understand that JavaScript can be included in my android studio project, thankfully from here: 
https://github.com/manifestinteractive/android-studio-filetypes/tree/master/settings

But I don't understand how to send javascript info to a java class.
I created a very simple node program to test this.

Practice.js:

```
// include Java Class file
const OrderJava = require('./Order.java');

// modify class contents
OrderJava.customer_name = "Blake Smith";
```

Order.java (same directory as Practice.js)

```
// Order.java: create a sample java class

public class Order {
    public String customer_name = new String("John Smith");
}
```

I receive the error after executing `node practice.js`:

```
/node/Order.java:3
public class Order {


Syntax Error: Unexpected token class
```

It doesn't seem as though node.js applications have support to modify java classes.

If I could modify java classes using node.js, then it's easy to create textViews and other activity elements in android studio.

Is there any Java class support for node.js applications?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Figured it out. You can run a "child_process" to execute terminal commands. Modifying a java class can easily be done by creating a file with a method that can modify the desired class, then executing that file with a child process. More info here: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html